# Chart.js with handlebar.js shows empty canvas

Tags: canvas, chart.js, handlebars.js

I'm trying to implement some charts using Handlebar.js in combination with Chart.js. So far I managed to get 2 charts working, but the third one is showing up as an empty canvas. I copied the code from the previous graph, but even then I just get an empty canvas. Replacing the data and labels with hardcoded arrays doesn't seem to work either.

When I log the values in the forEach loop, it prints the correct values, but when I try to log anything else, I get 'undefined'. Is this normal JavaScript behaviour?

At first I thought it was the result of some variables having the same name in the previous charts. But since this isn't causing problems between the first and second chart, and that renaming the variables still causes the problem, I dropped this idea.

```js
    {{#if roleSpread}}
    <section class="overallResult" style="background-color: #fff7ea;">

        <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center; width: 100%; vertical-align: top; color: grey;">

            <canvas id="roleChart" width="1000px" height="500px"></canvas>

            <script>
                var ctx = document.getElementById('roleChart');

                var averages = [];
                var roles = [];
                {{#each roleAvg}}
                    var avg = {{this.score}};
                    averages.push(avg);
                    var role = {{this.role}};
                    roles.push(role);
                {{/each}}


                var data = {
                    labels: roles,
                    datasets: [{
                        data: averages,
                        label: "Role average",
                        backgroundColor: 'rgb(245, 146, 37)'
                    }]
                }
                  var options = {
                    legend: false,
                    scales: {
                        yAxes: [{
                            display: true,
                            ticks: {
                                beginAtZero: true,
                                stepSize:10,
                                suggestedMax:100
                            }
                        }]
                    },
                    animation: false
                };
                var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                    type: 'bar',
                    data: data,
                    options: options
                });

            </script>
        </div>
    </section>
    {{/if}}
```

After some testing I noticed that when I replace the forEach with the forEach of another chart, it works. The other chart uses Numbers

```
//This does not work
[
  { role: 'analyst', score: 34 },
  { role: 'manager', score: 27 },
  { role: 'other', score: 37 }
]

//This works
[
  { score: 26, count: 1 },
  { score: 28, count: 1 },
  { score: 34, count: 1 },
  { score: 37, count: 1 }
]
```

Comment: "...but when I try to log anything else, I get 'undefined'". What else are you trying to log?

Comment: @76484 I tried logging the ctx object, the averages array and the roles array. All of those showed up as undefined. This also happened in the working charts so I assume this is just some JavaScript behaviour

Comment: I don't see how it can work if `ctx` is `undefined`.

Comment: There isn't enough information here to determine why this isn't working.

Comment: @76484 I've added some more information that I found. I think it has something to do with either the format of the data, or the forEach being incorrect (which seems unlikely since it follows the same pattern as my other charts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that it will not work if you have String values for your `role` properties.

This has to do with the fact that you are using Handlebars to produce executable JavaScript.

The code that needs to be updated is:

```
var role = {{this.role}};
roles.push(role);
```

This code outputs JavaScript. When the `role` values are numbers, the output looks like:

```
var role = 26;
roles.push(role);
```

The above is perfectly valid JavaScript. However, when `role` is a String, the output becomes:

```
var role = analyst;
roles.push(role);
```

Since there are no quotes around `analyst`, the JavaScript engine thinks it is an identifier for a variable, but since it cannot find a variable named `analyst`, it throws a [Reference Error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ReferenceError).

As we need our `role` values to be valid JavaScript Strings, we will need to ensure there are quotes around them. The updated template would look like:

```
var role = "{{this.role}}";
roles.push(role);
```

Which will produce the following JavaScript:

```
var role = "analyst";
roles.push(role);
```